# OpenSSL error "data greater than mod len"

Tags: c#, c++, encryption, openssl, cryptography

I have a client/server setup that consists of a server written in C++ using `OpenSSL` and a client written in C# using `Aes/RSACryptoServiceProvider`. I generate an RSA key pair on both sides and send each side the public key. Then, when I'm ready to send a message I generate an Aes key/iv and encrypt the message with this, and then encrypt the Aes key (and the iv too? I've tried both encrypting it and not encrypting it, but both give me the same error, which I will mention in a bit) with the public key of the recipient and then send the Aes encrypted key, the iv and the encrypted message. However, when I try to send from the client to the server, I get an OpenSSL error that reads "data greater than mod len" when using `EVP_OpenInit`.

Here is how I generate the data in C#:

```
var keyPair = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048); //server uses 2048 too (added on Edit)
var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
//OpenSSL uses the EVP_CIPHER* EVP_aes_256_cbc()
aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
aes.KeySize = 256; //bits
aes.GenerateKey();
aes.GenerateIV();
var message = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("test data");
var eMessage = new byte[4096];
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(eMessage))
{
    var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor();
    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(stream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
        await cryptoStream.WriteAsync(message, 0, message.Length);
    }
}
string eMessageString = null;
for (int i = 0; i < eMessage.Length; i++)
{
    if (eMessage[i] == '\0')
    {
        eMessageString = Convert.ToBase64String(eMessage, 0, i-1);
    }
}
var eKey = Convert.ToBase64String(keyPair.Encrypt(aes.Key, false));
var eIV = Convert.ToBase64String(aes.IV); //may not need to encrypt
```

I know my C++ implementation works as OpenSSL correctly reads in the client public key and I can encrypt/decrypt data using the `EVP_Seal`/`EVP_Open` functions when using a different key generated through `OpenSSL` on the server. So, I'm not sure what's causing this error, but I think I have an idea. Could it be the way that the key/iv/encrypted message is encoded when I'm sending the data to the server? Or could it be the differences in implementation between `OpenSSL` and C#? Or maybe something I'm not catching altogether?

EDIT: Here is the requested code for how I use `EVP_OpenInit`.

```
BlueSOD::Encryption::DecryptionData BlueSOD::Encryption::EncryptionFactory::Decrypt2(DecryptionWork2 && work)
{
    DecryptionData data;
    EVP_PKEY* privateKey = work.privateKey.get();
    auto encryptionKey = (unsigned char*)work.info.key.c_str();
    auto encryptionIV = (unsigned char*)work.info.iv.c_str();
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ptr cipherCtxPtr{ AcquireCipherCtx() };
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX* cipher = cipherCtxPtr.get();
    int status;

    //ERROR HAPPENS HERE
    status = EVP_OpenInit(cipher, m_Cipher, encryptionKey, work.info.key.size(), encryptionIV, privateKey);
    cout << ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), nullptr) << endl;
    CheckForError(status, "EVP_OpenInit failed.");

    int bufferLength = work.cipherText.size() + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH;
    auto buffer = make_unique<unsigned char[]>(bufferLength);
    auto cipherTemp = (unsigned char*)work.cipherText.c_str();

    status = EVP_OpenUpdate(cipher, buffer.get(), &bufferLength, cipherTemp, work.cipherText.size());
    CheckForError(status, "EVP_OpenUpdate failed.");

    status = EVP_OpenFinal(cipher, buffer.get(), &bufferLength);
    CheckForError(status, "EVP_OpenFinal failed.");

    data.plainText = CreateSecureString(buffer.get(), bufferLength);

    return move(data);
}
```

Comment: Note that you are currently using the highly secure OAEP padding (`true` in RSA encryption). OpenSSL is likely to default to PKCS#1 v1.5 padding. Neither PKCS#1 v1.5 *or* CBC/PKCS#7 is secure for use in transport protocols due to padding oracle attacks and the lack of authentication / integrity protection.

Comment: I switched to `false` and I still get the same error.

Comment: RSACryptoServiceProvider ignores set attempts on KeySize.  To use RSACryptoServiceProvider to create a 2048-bit key you need to use `new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048)`.

Comment: Didn't help :( but thanks

Answer (score 2):

`Encoding.Default.GetString` won't work. The IV, wrapped key and ciphertext are all binary, and (as good as) indistinguishable from random. That means that the encoding may go wrong as not all bytes will map to characters. This means that information is lost. Try and use base 64 encoding instead.

Your IV, wrapped key and ciphertext should also be distinguishable from each other. This is however not hard as the IV has the block size of the underlying cipher (16 bytes for AES/CBC), the wrapped key has the same size in bytes of the modulus (or the RSA key size), and the ciphertext, well, is the rest. In other words you might as well simply concatenate them all.

So your hunch was right.

Comment: I have since tried using `Convert.ToBase64String` (and have changed my code to reflect this) and I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you print out the wrapped `eKey` in hexadecimals on both sides (you can find such a function here on stackoverflow if you don't know how). If those byte arrays are not identical then there is something wrong before entering RSA decrypt.

Comment: I tried the raw string and the hexadecimal string. The raw strings are equal but the hexadecimal strings are different? I'm not sure how that is. Both sides put out the same hexadecimal string with the test data, but not with the `eKey`.

Comment: The idea is to compare the output of RSA encryption with the input of RSA decryption. That two sides encrypt to different values is OK. Each encryption will be different from a previous encryption, enen when using the same key.

Comment: I took @andy 's advice and decoded the string from base64 and I get the same hexadecimal value on each side now, but I still get the same error from `EVP_OpenInit`.

Answer (score 1):

RSA 4096 w/ OAEP can only encrypt 446 bytes of data ([see 7.1 of RSA RFC 2437](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2437#section-7.1)), and RSA 2048 w/ OAEP can only encrypt 245 bytes (still should be plenty of room for 16 + 32 bytes for IV and symmetric key). I don't see anywhere that you set the key length for the RSA provider, so it may be failing for some reason to encrypt the AES key.

Can you provide at least the line at which the server code throws the exception? What are you providing for the `eki` parameter (symmetric secret key length) in [`EVP_OpenInit`](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:EVP_OpenInit(3))? Are you performing the Base64 decoding of the symmetric key before attempting to decrypt it using RSA on the server?

And for the record, you do not need to encrypt the IV before transmitting, but it has no negative impact (other than computation cost) to do so.

**Update:**

It is always helpful when debugging crypto issues to reduce the number of steps in each statement so you can find where the error is occurring. I'd recommend breaking out the last few statements of your client code into individual steps and walking through them (i.e. RSA encryption and Base64-encoding on separate lines).

So you can now compare the following values on client and server and they are byte-for-byte equal (no extra `0x00`, etc.)?

```
Reference    |    Client                           |    Server
------------------------------------------------------------------
    A        |    keyPair.Encrypt(aes.Key, false)  |    ek
 Base64E(A)  |    eKey                             |    ??
  len(A)     |    len(A)                           |  len(ek)
```

You mentioned in another comment that you compared the hex-encoded value of the Base64-decoded, encrypted key on both client and server and it was identical? Can you try just using the client & server to encrypt and decrypt an arbitrary plaintext message (<< 245 bytes in order to ensure that OAEP or PKCS#1 v1.5 padding does not then exceed 245 bytes) with that key pair to ensure everything is correct?

I'm not particularly familiar with the C# implementation -- is there something additional you need to do to replicate `EVP_SealInit` on the client?

Comment: I took your advice and decoded the information on the server first as well as adding `keyPair.KeySize = 2048` on the client to bring it inline with the key size the server uses. Also, I added the code you requested at the bottom of my post in the edit.

Comment: I added an update in my answer to allow for formatting.

Answer (score 0):

My issue lied in how the message, key, and iv were encoded on the client and decoded on the server. The client encoded them in base64, so it had to be decoded on the server in order for OpenSSL to understand them (OpenSSL uses raw bytes rather than an encoding scheme).

EDIT: There also seems to be a conflict between the C# implementation and the OpenSSL implementation. The C# Aes implementation does not seem to match the OpenSSL exactly. I get the correct plain text when decrypting in OpenSSL, but there is a bunch of garbage data that follows and `EVP_OpenFinal` causes an error that says "bad decrypt". If anyone knows a way around this, please let me know! I have tried the openssl.net API, but it throws an error if I try to use BIO.